# Best forum for project management resources

Tags: project-management

What is the best online forum site about project management? It must cover PM-related news, articles, case studies and discussion boards.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit**

How fast things change? I just heard about [Cornelius Fichtner's](http://www.thepmpodcast.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=20&Itemid=35) new project: [Project Managment Opinions](http://www.project-management-opinions.com/). It has a section on [resources](http://www.project-management-opinions.com/index.php?option=com_mtree&task=listcats&cat_id=69&Itemid=8). Already this newly launched site looks like a good meta site.

**Previously on Stackoverflow....**

I don't think there one site for what you want. The resources i use are:

**Podcasts:**

[PM Podcast](http://www.thepmpodcast.com/) - very good. The latest episode on the PMI virtual communities will point you to further resources on SIGs in PMI and how they are changing.

[PM Lessons Learned](http://pmlessonslearned.blogspot.com/) - messy site, but worth subscribing and listening to the most recent episodes (very good ones on risk and softskills)

**Sites:**

[GanttHead](http://www.gantthead.com/) - very busy site... i've never used anything from the site but there are a lot of links and forums i think.

**Groups:**

[PMI](http://www.pmi.org/)  - a great resource if you are a member. Also has PM news on it's homepage for everyone. Some of the work in SIGs sounds very interesting.

[Your local PMI chapter](http://wa.pmichapters-australia.org.au/) - OK so this is my local chapter. Worthwhile investigating your own. I've had a very small involvement with mine and found them very approachable and useful.

Answer (score 0):

In the earlier days, [Joel's site](http://www.joelonsoftware.com) had more of a project management lean.

Browse the archive [here](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/Archive.html).

Answer (score 0):

**http://www.manager-tools.com**
Someone pointed me to a podcast there once.. might be worth a look. Never been there too long.. got a more programmer bent of mind.

Answer (score 0):

The Project Management Institute (pmi.org) may be a great place if you're looking for recognized, professional project management.

Answer (score 0):

I would pimp my own - but I won't.  I highly recommend checking out Ed Yourdon and Caper Jones sites:
http://www.yourdon.com/

http://www.spr.com/

Outside of that there's pmi.org, but they're mostly on the look out for selling pmp certification.  There's also Agile Alliance 
http://agilealliance.com/

Overall...not much good out there for PM's